# Neo4j: possible to create an alternative to node ids based on integer increments?

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j's nodes tend to be set on the basis of integer increments. I can see this having issues in an application that needs to merge multiple two databases. Is it possible to configure the database to use another format, such as UUIDs to identify each node?

Comment: There's no built-in support for this yet (in version 1.2). Maybe someone can come up with a good way to implement it on top of Neo4j?

Comment: This would be useful for applications that have existing integer/long ids - would be much neater to be able to inject these into the Neo4J node constructors rather than having to maintain them as additional properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not.

[Stack Overflow requires 30 chars]

Answer (score 8):

What I have done before is set a property on each node to store a GUID and created an index using the IndexService that creates a GUID index. I have then worked with that index to retrieve nodes based on GUID rather than the internal Neo4J generated ids.

Comment: +1, I we do the same thing in http://github.com/scholrly/neo4django to implement AutoProperties.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neo4j extension that adds uuid properties to each node.

https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-uuid

Quote from the author why you should use uuid if you are dealing with multiple database:

> ... node.getId() is a bad choice since after deletion of a node its id might be recycled.